# Basic Bash - If/Then with Boolean Operator

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

As you can see I set up a simple script to ping google(8.8.8.8) that should respond back with "Good Ping"

```
if [ "ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep 64 | cut -c 1-2" == '64' ];  then echo "Good Ping"; fi
```

But it never responds with its echo statement

At the same time I can run:

```
ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep 64 | cut -c 1-2
```

This resolves to '64' without an issue

I don't understand the top script will never print "Good Ping", could someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep 64 | cut -c 1-2` is never equal to 64, but that's what you test for. If you want to test a command, use command substitution:

```
if [ $(ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 | grep 64 | cut -c 1-2) == 64 ] ; then
    echo Good Ping
fi
```

`` `...` `` can be used instead of `$(...)`.

Comment: In general it's good practice to use `$() ` over `\`\`` as long as the shell supports it because nesting is easier that way.

Comment: ahhhh I was trying to compare that string and not its result... Thanks Choroba